# Laravel breadcrumbs not picking view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4, breadcrumbs

I am using https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs package.

I followed all the instructions as mentioned and breadcrumbs are generating perfectly.

But its not picking the breadcrumbs template that i mentioned in the config.

Here is my config code

```
return ['view' => 'layouts.partials._breadcrumbs'];
```

And here is the output that I am getting

**What I am getting right now**
[image]

**What should I get**

[image]

I am sure that its picking the default bootstrap theme.

Here is my code directory structure where I placed the view

[image]

Comment: Change `'view' => 'admin/partials/_breadcrumbs'` to `'view' => 'layouts/partials/_breadcrumbs'`. Because `_breadcrumbs.blade.php` file is in `layouts/partials` directory as you defined in your question!

Comment: sorry that was mistake while uploading, i edited my question again and its still not picking that template.

Comment: if it weren't finding a view laravel would throw an exception, what does your view look like?

Comment: Ok, but why you used dots instead of `/`

Comment: HirenGohel it accepted dot as well and slashed too. I tried with the slashes too but its not working thats why i tried dots. 

dops here is my view for breadcrumbs

https://imgur.com/a/pGX7V

Comment: Check `@if (count($breadcrumbs))` instead of `@if($breadcrumbs)`. Check is there count or not?

Comment: Thanks but it was a cache issue. Its working by clearing config:cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. I sort it out myself. It was issue of config cached. By doing clearing config:cache its working fine now.

Comment: helped me too, bro!